# How to generate random number between 1 to 9 in c program, then assign that number to one of three things and it shouldn't be same each time?

Tags: c

```
srand(time(NULL));
int nRandonNumber = rand()%9+1;
printf("%d\n",nRandonNumber);
```

How to generate random numbers between 1 to 9 in the c program, then assign that number to one of three things, and it shouldn't be the same each time?

Comment: *What* shouldn't "be the same each time"? The random number you generated? The "three things" (whatever they are)? Something else?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Looks like you already solved the given task yourself!?

Comment: *shouldn't be the same* - means it is not a random number you are looking for but some random permutation.

Comment: Put the values 1 thru 9 in an array. Randomly swap the elements around. Use the first three elements.

Comment: *three things* is not a type.

Comment: You shouldn't use a seed that is dependent on the seconds on the clock. You should probably use the system PRNG, and that will be different per platform.

Comment: For the "random swapping" @WeatherVane have mentioned you might want to use the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm

Comment: You could create an array of random numbers using a decimal expansion of the square root of a numbers such as 15 or 2.015 - after the decimal point; C will do this to 48-54 decimal places. Or create random numbers in the real world and create an array. Both these methods mean you can start extracting array elements at a different place each time.  Functions like rand() are not truly random, although I realise I'm being pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of generating 3 numbers bewteen `1` and `9`, shuffle an array with the numbers `1` to `9`... then select the first 3, obviously different, elements.

```
int arr[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
shuffle(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr); // implementing shuffle left as an exercise
printf("%d %d %d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

Suggestion for `shuffle()`: [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: I tried  your code but it gave me an error

Comment: There will be no error if you properly define the `shuffle()` function.